# about homeomorphism on subspace topology of $ \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, manifolds

Consider $X=\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \cup \{p,q\}$, that is $X$ is the union of the reals minus $0$, and two points. Consider sets of the type

$U_a = (-a,0) \cup \{p\} \cup (0,a)$

$V_a=(-a,0) \cup \{q\} \cup (0,a)$

where $a >0$. And let

$\mathcal{B}=\{U_a\}_{a>0} \cup \{V_a\}_{a >0} \cup \{ \text{all open intervals of} \hspace{2mm} \mathbb{R} \hspace{2mm} \text{not containing the origin} \}$

Then $\tau=\{\bigcup_{\alpha} B_{\alpha} \big | B_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{B} \}$.

> 1-Show that $(X,\tau)$ is locally Euclidean and second countable, but not Hausdorff.

For any two positive real numbers $c,d$ define $$I_p(-c,d)=]-c,0[\cup\{p\}\cup]0,d[.$$

> 2-Prove that the interval $I_{p}(-c, d)$ is homeomorphic to the interval $(-c, d)$

for 1) $(X,\tau)$ is locally Euclidean and second countable because $ \mathbb{R}$ is locally Euclidean and second countable ($X$ is subspace topology of $ \mathbb{R}$ with Euclidean meter). also $(X,\tau)$ is not Hausdorff  because any neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ and any neighbourhood $V$ of $q$ then $ U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

for 2) let $h\colon I_p(-c,d)\to (-c,d)$ defined by
\begin{split}
h(x)&=x\quad\text{for}\;x\in]-c,0[\;\cup\;]0,d[\\
h(p)&=0
\end{split}

then Clearly $h$ is bijective and continuous (with  pasting lemma).

> Now, we must prove that $h^{-1}$ is continuous or equivalently, that $h$ is an open map.then $h$ is a homeomorphism

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @G.Chiusole . how we can prove that $h^{-1}$ is continuous or equivalently, that $h$ is an open map.then $h$ is a homeomorphism ?

Comment: Have you tried writing down $h^{-1}$ explicitly, and use pasting?

Comment: @G.Chiusole . so with definition of $h$ , $h^{-1} = h$   ?

Comment: No, $h^{-1}$ is not _equal_ to $h$, but it is very similar. It maps 0 to p and any point which is not 0 to itself

Comment: How exactly did you apply the pasting lemma here?

Comment: You wrote "$X$ is subspace topology on $\mathbb R$", which makes no sense because $X$ is not even a subset of $\mathbb R$; subspace topology is only defined for subsets.

Comment: @G.Chiusole . $h$ is continuous on $(-c,0)$ and $ (0,d)$ and at $x=p$ .

Comment: @LeeMosher . So this topology is not equal to subspace topology? so $X$ is not euclidean and second  countable?

Comment: That is correct. Look at the definition of subspace topology, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). To repeat: a subspace topology of $\mathbb R$ starts with **a subset of $\mathbb R$**. Your $X$ is not **a subset of $\mathbb R$**.

Comment: @amirbahadory that alone does not justify the use of pasting. You either need all of the sets to be closed or all of them to open. How do you know that the function is continuous at $x = p$?

Comment: @LeeMosher .  My solution is wrong for  locally euclidean and second countable?

Comment: @G.Chiusole . I think now we can't  use pasting lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Any open set is a union of open intervals, and open intervals of $I_p(-c,d)$ are mapped to (basically the same) open intervals of $(-c,d)$.

By the way, $h$ can be extended to the whole space as $X\to\Bbb R$ (also set $h(q)=0$, of course), and that's continuous and open as well.

Comment: why $h$ is continuous ?

Comment: The preimage of an open interval is either itself if it didn't contain $0$ or is a union of $U_\varepsilon\cup V_\varepsilon$ with perhaps other open intervals.